# How to pass a second parameter to Javascript map

Tags: javascript

I need to pass an array index as a second parameter to Javascript .map() :

```
var arr1 = [25,50,75,90]
var arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5]

arr2.map(function(x){
  console.log( arr1[index] * x );
});
```

How can I iterate on arr1 while applying .map() to arr2?

Thanks!

Comment: `arr2.map(function(x,index){` You can receive the index as second parameter.

Comment: what do you do with unequal length?

Answer (score 4):

You don't pass a second parameter to `map`, you pass a second parameter to the function that you pass as a first (and only) parameter to `map`. When map, in turn invokes that function, it will call it with the current element as the first parameter, and the index of the current element as the second. (Map actually uses a third argument as well, which is the whole array being iterated).

So if you have code like:

```
arr2.map(function(item, index){
  console.log( item, index );
});
```

You'll get

```
25 0  
50 1  
75 2  
90 3
```

Comment: ok but what if I want to pass a third argument that has nothing to do with arr2 (or whatever array you call `map` on)? For example I wanna generate <div>s from an array with map, but I need to pass an argument `id` to each of the <div> generated. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

if what you need is an array like this:

```
var arr3 = [25 * 1, 50 * 2, 75 * 3, 90 * 4, 100 * 5];
```

you may use something like:

```
var arr1 = [25,50,75,90,100];
var arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5];
var arr3 = arr2.map(function(x, idx){ return x * arr1[idx]; });
```

Note both arrays should have the same length.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

The `map()` function provides a callback which takes three arguments: `currentValue`, `index`, `array`